How do we unit test a nested `@task` decorated method in apache airflow?
I have a DAG in apache airflow like so
@dag(
)
def taskflow():
    ....
    @task()
    def generate_args():
      return arglist

    run_pod = pod_operator(
        name="name",
        memory_gb=20,
        image="myimage",
        cmds=["poetry"],
        partial=True,
    ).expand(arguments=generate_args())

    run_pod


dag = taskflow()


I would like unit test the method generate_args  annotated with @Task , importing the Dag did not work, any solutions to test this nested , @task annotated generated_args method?
I am using poetry pytests to test it and would like the line coverage of lines of generate_args  to be fully covered.
